# copy a multi line variable to clipboard python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

my code calls a program and copies output to a variable

`info = os.popen('info filename').read()`

which outputs a multi line sting

```
line
line1 : ABC
line2 : (efg)
line3 : ABCDEFG! (hijkl)
......................................
```

lets say i want to delete `(efg)` from that variable 
so

```
info = info.replace('(egf)' , '')
```

now i want to copy the variable to clipboard. So i can paste it using selenium since that info string is very large and selenium in chrome types one key at a time it just scrambles all letters in `info` variable while typing

so if i can copy this variable to clipboard i should just be able to do

```
textarea.sendkeys(Keys.CONTROL , 'v')
```

i've heard about `pyperclip` but i cant use that

Comment: "i've heard about pyperclip but i cant use that", why not?

Comment: i'm using python 3.8 but running `pip3 install pyperclip` returns me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes` error to fix that i'd need `libffi-devel` i think but i'm working on a machine without sudo privileges